# Web page design optimised for 1024x768

Tags: html, html-table

I'm trying to create a web page that supports multiple resolutions, with 1024 being the minimum supported. Users with higher resolution will simply get white bars on the left and right of the web page.

There will be a banner at the top center of the page. Below that will be 2 images, one on the left and the other on the right.

Currently, I am using an HTML `<table>` to control the position of the images and banner to ensure that higher resolution monitors do not screw up my layout.

Here is my code:

```
<table style="width: 1024px; margin: auto; border: 0px">
  <tr>
  <td rowspan="2">
   <img alt="banner" class="float-left" src="img/banner.png" />
  </td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
  <td>
   <asp:ImageButton class="float-left" ID="ImageButton2" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/img_left.png" />
  </td>
  <td>
   <asp:ImageButton class="float-right" ID="ImageButton3" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/img/img_right.png" />
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The layout works as intended if I view it using a resolution higher than 1024, but if I use 1024 to view it, there are narrow white bars on the left and right of the page and I can scroll horizontally.

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I would recommend using a percentage for your width instead of pixels. By setting the width to 1024px, you're saying your table will *always* be 1024px wide. So on monitors with a less-than-1024 res, you'll see the horizontal scrollbars. Try setting the width to 80% and see if it works better.

Comment: If you're using `<table>` to do layout, you're probably doing it wrong. Use a `<div>`.

Comment: using div or setting the width didn't work, i am still getting the narrow white border around the page. i found a way to "mitigate" the issue by reducing the width of my banner img and did a background color for the div to make it look like a banner.

Answer (score 0):

What I would recommend doing is stating a max width. This will allow the site to still be 1024px and it won't scale up above that. From there, you could state a width of percentage.

max-width:1024px; width:95%;  (or 100%)

Hope this helped.